# How do add two columns using awk?

Tags: linux, awk, terminal

Hello I need to add two columns using awk, the colums are made of rational numbers.
example:

#/file

```
20.2 15
15.4 18.4
13.4 14.6
```

I tried using `awk '{print $1+$2}' /file`. I seem to be getting integer values `(25,43,27)`.
How do I get awk to print rational values?

Comment: `"{print $1+$2}"` -> `'{print $1+$2}'`

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for showing your efforts in your question. When I run `awk '{print $1+$2}'  Input_file` I get `35.2
33.8
28` which looks to have floating point numbers in its output. Also I am getting a syntax error(with your shown attempts) when I am quoting my `awk` program inside `"` an `awk` program should be quoted with `'.....'`(single quotes).

Comment: oh sorry I was using '{print $1+$2}' just made a mistake here

Comment: @Nitaaa, ok, I can't reproduce that issue on liunx, on which O.S you are using or which version of awk? Its always handy to mentioned these kind of details?

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new to linux, programing and stackoverflow.
mawk 1.3.4 20200120

Copyright 2008-2019,2020, Thomas E. Dickey

Copyright 1991-1996,2014, Michael D. Brennan

random-funcs:       srandom/random
regex-funcs:        internal
compiled limits:
sprintf buffer      8192
maximum-integer     2147483647,

and I am using ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS